# split ifstream on two ofstreams

Tags: c++, stl, iostream

there is a file (ifstream) ,
and I have to split this on two output files (ofstreams) using a parameter as a number of char for each file:

e.g. num_of_char = 3

in: abcdefghijk

out1:abcghi

out2:defjk

what is a most effective way to do this? 
(I suppose I have to use (ifstream).width(num_of_char); )
is there something like :
out1 << in;
??

Comment: There's `out1 << in.rdbuf();`, but it'll just dump all the contents of `in` into `out1`, you can't limit the number of bytes copied this way. Off the top, I don't see anything better than "read `N` bytes from `in` into memory, write them to `out1`, read `N` more bytes, write them to `out2`, lather, rinse, repeat".

Answer (score 0):

that is my current solution, 
by the way - is there unary bool value flip operation to avoid third line in the loop?

```
...
std::string s;
bool flag = true;
while (!is.eof()) {
    is >> std::setw(num_of_char ) >> s;
    (flag ? out1 : out2) << s;
    flag = !flag;
}
....
```